# Structured Haskell Mode [SHM]: How to delete single bracket or string quote by <backspace> or <del>?

Tags: haskell, plugins, emacs, key-bindings

Suppose I want to remove parentheses around some expression, e.g. I want to unwrap `(not True)`.

- Pressing `<backspace>` with the cursor standing right after closing parenthesis does not delete it, but the cursor jumps inside the parentheses (runs `shm/del`).
- Pressing `<delete>` when the cursor is placed over opening parenthesis deletes everything inside, including the parentheses themselves (runs `delete-char`).

The same goes with string double quote delimiters, curly brackets, square brackets, and I believe something else.

Is there some predefined function to unwrap expression in **SHM**? Or should I override this behaviour with some manual key bindings/actions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`structured-haskell-mode` is very heavily influenced by `paredit`, which is where it gets the basic movement and editing bindings from. You can see what commands `paredit` provides either by looking it up in the Emacs help system (easiest way: open up a lisp buffer, enable paredit, `C-h m`) or using this [handy cheatsheet](http://pub.gajendra.net/src/paredit-refcard.pdf) (which looks reasonable but I haven't read).

Also, this [video introduction](http://emacsrocks.com/e14.html) to `paredit` for Lisp is probably worth watching.

For your specific question: `M-s` deletes the current level of nesting. In `paredit` this works for parentheses, brackets or quotes, but it looks like shm only supports parentheses at the moment. You can invoke it anywhere inside an expression:

```
((a |b c) d e f)
M-s
(a b c d e f)
```

EDIT: As @ReinHenrichs pointed out, you have to expand the selection to the whole node using `M-a` before using `M-s` to delete the surrounding parentheses, which is why it wasn't working for me earlier.

In the meantime, a decent workaround would be to rebind `DEL` to something like `haskell-indentation-delete-backward-char` (or whatever is appropriate for your setup) so that you can delete structural characters as before. From a bit of experimenation, `shm` seems to gracefully degrade for code that doesn't parse properly, so this isn't too inconvenient.

Comment: Thank you, I've tried `M-s` within strings, expressions surrounded by parentheses, and square brackets, and every time I had nothing but error message `"Unsupported node type for splicing"`. It's pity, cause I've already delighted (: suppose I have to report issue.

Comment: @Geradlus_RU: The fact that it doesn't work for anything but parentheses is noted in its documentation. The fact that it also doesn't work for complex expressions in parentheses is probably a bug though.

Comment: It does work for complex expressions in parenthesis but you have to expand the selection first with `M-a`. For example, given `(f| a b)` with point at `|`, `M-a` will expand the selection and then `M-s` will remove the surrounding parens, giving `|f a b`. It's helpful to set the face for the selection to something easy to see but not too distracting.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs: Oh, I did not realize this. The selection is invisible with my default settings, and I just expected it to work like `paredit`. I'll add a note to my answer about it.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs, tried it out, can confirm this works! Thanks a lot! Still have to find mentioned face customization.

Answer (score 1):

Put this keybinding into your `emacs` configuration file:

`(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-d") 'delete-pair)`

Now you can place the point before the opening part of the pair (parentheses, square brackets, quotes etc.) or use `M-a` in SHM to go to the next outer pair and press `C-c C-d` to delete the pair.